# How to pass and consume Flow1 materialized value into Flow2 using Akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am learning Akka and trying to understand the working of GraphStage, but I am struggling with **materialized value** usage.

I want to help to resolve following question:

> How to consume materialized value of first flow into second flow?

Please provide pointers if any

Thanks

Comment: An example of what you're trying to achieve would help here.

Comment: Why do you want to materialize value of first flow and then use it in second flow? You could just materialize the values at the end after connecting all the flows. And an example of code would really help to understand the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

It took me some time to think your question through. In short, my answer will be: your question is meaningless per my understanding of akka-stream. Below is an extended explanation. Also my knowledge is limited, so in case if I have assumed something incorrectly - please comment and let's learn together.

Before thinking how can we consumed materialized value of a `Flow` we need first to have an example of a `Flow` with materialized value different from `NotUsed` - one used in most out-of-the-box flows.
So, I've coded a simple `Flow` which just passes all upstream elements through but has a counter embedded which counts total elements passed.
Here goes the code:

```
class FlowWithCounter extends GraphStageWithMaterializedValue[FlowShape[Int, Int], Future[Int]]{
    val in:Inlet[Int] = Inlet("Inlet_of_FlowWithCounter")
    val out:Outlet[Int] = Outlet("Outlet of FlowWithCounter")

    override def shape: FlowShape[Int, Int] = FlowShape(in, out)

    override def createLogicAndMaterializedValue(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): (GraphStageLogic, Future[Int]) = {
      val materializedValue = Promise[Int]()
      val logic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
        private var counter: Int = 0

        setHandler(
          in,
          new InHandler {
            override def onPush(): Unit = {
              val elem = grab(in)
              counter += 1
              push(out, elem)
            }

            override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
              materializedValue.success(counter)
              super.onUpstreamFinish()
            }
          }
        )

        setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
          override def onPull(): Unit = {
            pull(in)
          }
        })
      }
      (logic, materializedValue.future)
    }
  }
```

As you can see the materialized value type is Future[Int]. Thus when the stream is completed the materializer will be able to fetch this value and use it if we instruct it to do so.

Now few important observations:

1. the `createLogicAndMaterializedValue` method will be called not by stream `Materializer` at the moment when we will run our stream. So we should return at that moment some pointer which will hold the materialized value at stream completion moment. This is usually done in form of `Future[T]` naturally.
2. As noted [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html):

   > // All state MUST be inside the GraphStageLogic,
   >
   > // never inside the enclosing GraphStage.
   >
   > // This state is safe to access and modify from all the
   >
   > // callbacks that are provided by GraphStageLogic and the
   >
   > // registered handlers.

   In our example this means that we only have access to the `counter` variable inside the `new GraphStageLogic(shape) {...}` constructor. We cannot reference the `counter` itself at the line where we return the `(logic, materializedValue.future)` pair.

I have not found in DSL any means to query the materialized value of a stream component. Only with help of methods like `toMat`, `viaMat` we can tell the materializer to propagate the materialized value of components downstream. And only with help of methods like `run` we can extract the final materialized value of the whole stream in the end.

Noticed that our example flow completes the promise with the `counter` value inside the

```
override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
  materializedValue.success(counter)
  super.onUpstreamFinish()
}
```

when upstream is completed.

Here is how we actually wire this sample flow, propagate its materialized value through stream stages and consume it in the end, when the whole stream completes:

```
import akka.stream.stage._

object Main {
  import scala.concurrent._
  import akka._
  import akka.actor._
  import akka.stream._
  import akka.stream.scaladsl._

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestSystem")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  import system.dispatcher

  class FlowWithCounter extends GraphStageWithMaterializedValue[FlowShape[Int, Int], Future[Int]]{....}

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val source:Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(15 to 25)
    val flow:Flow[Int, Int, Future[Int]] = Flow.fromGraph(new FlowWithCounter)
    val sink:Sink[Int, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach(println)

    val completion:(Future[Int], Future[Done]) = ((source.viaMat(flow)(Keep.right)).toMat(sink)(Keep.both)).run()
    completion._2 foreach{_ =>
      completion._1 foreach{count =>
        println("Our flow processed " + count + " elements.")
        system.terminate()
      }
    }
  }

}
```

So the materialized value of our flow only available at the stage completion.
`Flow` component is agnostic of materialized values of the upstream source and downstream sink. To my knowledge only materializer and stream interpreter will be able to fetch those materialize values and propagate them appropriately.

Maybe your question has some meaning for the infinite streams, I can imagine a situation when 2nd flow needs to check the counter embedded in the 1st flow in some logic condition - but I don't know how to achieve this. Maybe someone will explain in other answers.

Comment: Yes, I have situation where I want to consume the materialized value of first flow into second flow and I have wrote GraphStageWithMaterializedValue but I was struggling with consuming that value, your answer is helpful to understand GraphStage in better way. As I learning It may possible that my approach is wrong towards the solution, I will think over that is for sure. Thanks @Alexander for your time and efforts.

Comment: One possible way based on this example would be to slightly modify the flow, so it is of the type `Flow[Int, (Int, Int), Future[Int])`. Let's modify the line `push(out, elem)` to `push(out, (elem, counter))`. That way whatever is downstream the flow will receive the original element together with the current value of the counter.

Comment: Great answer. Here is a simpler version of your custom flow which does not require to write your own implementation of a `Flow` class: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/Ofnx_XzWrTU/XfENcfktIgAJ